# Automatic patching breaks packages

Tags: ubuntu, security, package-management

In our organization our IT Department regularly pushing the OS patches to our project production servers (Ubuntu-18.04 LTS & Ubuntu-20.04 LTS) and due to this our application (Docker, Kubernetes, MYSQL, System kernel and etc) are automatically getting upgraded to latest version and few applications are showing service related errors. This is causing lot of issues with running application and it is affecting our production. We need to spend lot time to resolve issues arises due to automatic patching.

Have discussed many times with our IT Department to stop patching but they are saying can't stop the automatic updates, it will cause security vulnerabilities issues.

Our IT automatic patching method is recommended in production environment? So kindly let me know how this handled in other companies?

Some thoughts/suggestions on this matter will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked for the root causes of why patching breaks things? Are your applications relying on some unspecified or broken behavior, and failing when it gets changed/fixed? Are you programming in version checks of the form `check (version == X)` when they should be `check (version >= X)` instead? Is your application installation incorrectly changing/replacing some files that are part of some other packages, and so the changes get overridden when those packages are updated? Or something else?

Comment: Since we have various DevOps applications running in those few are highly rely on kernel, and few applications due to upgrade stopped automatically, this causes lot of inconvenience  to prod environment users.

Comment: A kernel update typically means the system was rebooted. Were your applications provisioned without service files/init scripts to start them automatically at boot, or did the applications fail to start for some other reason? If you rely on custom kernel modules, you should use DKMS or some other mechanism to allow rebuilding your custom kernel modules against an updated kernel automatically when necessary. If your application requires staying with a vulnerable kernel version, it means your software solution as a whole will be vulnerable, and a customer will seek new solutions.

Comment: @telcoM Regarding "why patching breaks things?", one of the items the question mentions is MySQL, where patches require stopping and starting `mysqld`.  I.e., induce an outage for that `mysqld` instance.  This would be applications relying on **specified** behavior (the service is up), and the solution doesn't rest solely on the shoulders of the application developers.  (Patch MySQL on primaries and replicas in the wrong order, and you can break replication, which is emphatically not the application developers' fault)  Some things require planning/coordination of all teams, not just app Devs.

Comment: @telcoM sorry if that sounded like I was scolding you, I wanted to explain to the larger audience how some things can be solved by the application developers, while others have to be solved by multiple teams working together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pushing updated/patched packages (which are in effect dependencies for your custom application code) to production without first testing them in non-production is bad.  It's every bit as bad as pushing changes in your own custom application code (or dependencies, like libraries/classes/modules) to production without first testing them in non-production.

Security patches are important, but so is your uptime and ability to meet your Service Level Agreements (SLAs) to your customers.  You can be patched and very secure, but if you lose all your customers because the patches keep breaking your service, everyone loses.

Your organization needs to work out a compromise where patch levels stay stable (unchanging) for a reasonable period of time (so SLAs to customers are not affected), and then the OS patches are put into the normal non-production test environments in the same sequence as your application code:  Dev, QA, Integration, Staging, etc., and applied to production along with the application code that was tested to work with the OS patches.

Comment: Thanks Sotto Voce.